# how to store json array response using retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to call an api endpoint and display the associated response in my android app.
The api takes a parameter user_name and return response of that user.
Response is in json array consisting json of date, location and img (base64).

**RESPONSE**

```
[
   {
        "id": "602a1901a54781517ecb717c",
        "date": "2021-02-15T06:47:29.191000",
        "location": "mall",
        "img": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAIBAQEBAQIBAQECAgICAgQDAgICAgUEBAMEBgUGBgYFBgYGBwkIBgcJBwYGCAsICQoKCgoKBggLDAsKDAkKCgr/2wBDAQICAgICAgUDAwUKBwYHCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgr/wAARCASvBLADASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/
}
]
```

the issue I am facing is I am not able to store the response and parse it.
I am using retrofit for this.
There is no issue in the api call the server gets a successfull request the issue is in the client side (android app).
Here is the code that i currently have.
**ApiInterface.java**

```
interface ApiInterface {  
    @FormUrlEncoded  
    @POST("end_point")  
    Call<List<Task>>getstatus(@Field("user_name") String user_name);  
  }
```

**Task.java**

```
public class Task {  
  @SerializedName("user_name")  
  public String user_name;  
  public Task(String user_name) {  
      user_name = user_name.substring(1, user_name.length()-1);  
      this.user_name= user_name;  
  }  
  public String getUser() {  
      return user_name;  
  }
  }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
private void LoginRetrofit(String user_name) {  
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()  
            .baseUrl("url")  
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())  
            .build();  
  
    final ApiInterface request = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);  
    Call<List<Task>> call = request.getstatus(user_name);  
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "user_name" + " " + call.request(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Task>>() {  
        @Override  
  public void onResponse(Call<List<Task>> call, Response<List<Task>> response) {  
            try { 
                List<Task> rs=response.body();  
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response" +  " "+rs, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            }  
            catch (Exception e)  
            {  
                Log.d("REsponse error",e.getMessage());  
            }  
        }  
  
        @Override  
  public void onFailure(Call<List<Task>> call, Throwable t) {  
            Log.d("Error",t.getMessage());  
        }  
    });    
}

This is the response which is being returned.
```

Comment: are you getting the success response in Postman and null in android after updated Task model?

Comment: After updated Task model I am getting com.example.Mask_net.Task@5acaeca in response. It is working properly in postman.

Comment: Ok so you are getting response but you are logging or printing the model which just prints object address not the data. So you must print the value of the object. I am posting answer so update it in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `MainActivity.java` file, update the code as below as you are printing `rs` object in your toast message, it prints only the *object address* not the value in it. So to print the value of the object you received, you must call the methods of the object to get value like as.

**MainActivity.java**

```
private void LoginRetrofit(String user_name) {  
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()  
            .baseUrl("url")  
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())  
            .build();  
  
    ...  
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Task>>() {  
        @Override  
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Task>> call, Response<List<Task>> response) {  
            try { 
                List<Task> rs=response.body();
                if(rs.size() > 0){
                    Task user = rs.get(0);
                    String id = user.getId();
                    String location = user.getLocation();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Response : Id="+id+" and location="+location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                
            }  
            catch (Exception e)  
            {  
                Log.d("REsponse error",e.getMessage());  
            }  
        }  
  
        ... 
    });    
}
```

and update the `Task` model as

**Task.java**

```
public class Task { 
    @SerializedName("id") public String id; 
    @SerializedName("date") public String date; 
    @SerializedName("location") public String location; 
    @SerializedName("img") public String img; 

    public Task(String id, String date, String location, String img) { 
        this.id=id; 
        this.date=date; 
        this.location=location; 
        this.img=img; 
    }

    public String getId(){ return this.id; }
    public String getDate(){ return this.date; }
    public String getLocation(){ return this.location; }
    public String getImg(){ return this.img; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data model class variables should be serialized or to have names as same as in the response , so that retrofit can be able to bind response values to your model variables .
Also you must have a variable in your model class for each key-value pair in your response that you want to use .

check this [example](https://medium.com/@prakash_pun/retrofit-a-simple-android-tutorial-48437e4e5a23) to get how retrofit really work .

Comment: I did exactly what u asked for but still i am getting null in response. Following is my updated model class      public class Task {
    @SerializedName("id")
    public String id;
    @SerializedName("date")
    public String date;
    @SerializedName("location")
    public String location;
    @SerializedName("img")
    public String img;

    public Task(String id, String date, String location, String img)
    {
        this.id=id;
        this.date=date;
        this.location=location;
        this.img=img;
    }
}